# Python - Archivo de texto a LaTeX

Tags: python, txt, latex

Actualmente estoy realizando múltiples transformaciones de un archivo .txt a LaTeX mediante el siguiente código:

```
from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, LineBreak, Section, Subsection, Math, Alignat, LargeText, Center, MediumText
from pylatex.utils import bold, italic, NoEscape
import os as os

class Math_LaTeX ():
    def __init__(self, doc):
        #---Inicializamos---
        self.doc = doc

        #---De aqui sacamos las ecuaciones del archivo .txt---
        equations = self.Read()

        #---Creamos el documento Latex---
        self.Create(equations)

        #---Creamos el PDF---
        self.doc.generate_pdf(filepath = TituloPDF, clean_tex = False, compiler = 'pdflatex')

    def Read(self):
        data = open(archivotxt, 'rt')
        equations = data.readlines()
        eqs = []
        for eq in equations:
            eqs.append(' '.join([line.strip() for line in eq.strip().splitlines()]))
        return eqs

    def Create(self, equations): 
        for eq in equations:
            with self.doc.create(Alignat(numbering = False, escape = False)) as math_eq:
                math_eq.append(eq)        
geometry_options = {
        "head": "0.5cm",
        "left": "0.5cm",
        "right": "0.5cm",
        "bottom": "2.5cm"
        }
doc = Document(geometry_options = geometry_options, inputenc = 'utf8')
Math_LaTeX(doc)
if os.path.exists(archivotxt):
    os.remove(archivotxt)
else:
    print("El archivo no existe")
```

Esto me crea el archivo en LaTeX y después lo transforma en PDF dejando unicamente el PDF que es justo lo que yo necesito, esto es lo que obtengo:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{head=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\begin{alignat*}{2}%
{\left( 3 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( -0.1 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( -0.2 \right) {x_{3}} = {7.85} }%
\end{alignat*}%
\begin{alignat*}{2}%
{\left( 0.1 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( 7 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( -0.3 \right) {x_{3}} = {-19.3} }%
\end{alignat*}%
\begin{alignat*}{2}%
{\left( 0.3 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( -0.2 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( 10 \right) {x_{3}} = {71.4} }%
\end{alignat*}%
\text{ -------------------------------------------------------------------------- }%
\end{alignat*}%
\begin{alignat*}{2}%
\text{Entonces la solución estaría dada por:}%
\end{alignat*}%
\begin{alignat*}{2}%
X = \begin{bmatrix}  x_{1} \\  x_{2} \\  x_{3} \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}  3.0 \\  -2.5 \\  7.0 \end{bmatrix}%
\end{alignat*}%
\end{document}
```

Sin embargo, me di cuenta que personalizar las opciones sobre todo estética es bastante difícil, por lo que me decidí por escribir el archivo .txt con todas las opciones que busco de esta forma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{head=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead[]{Ejercicio 01}
\begin{document}


$ {\left( 3 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( -0.1 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( -0.2 \right) {x_{3}} = {7.85} } $ 

$ {\left( 0.1 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( 7 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( -0.3 \right) {x_{3}} = {-19.3} } $

$ {\left( 0.3 \right) {x_{1}} +\left( -0.2 \right) {x_{2}} +\left( 10 \right) {x_{3}} = {71.4} } $


\newpage
\lhead[]{Ejercicio 02}

$ k = {2},x^{\left( {2} \right)}={\begin{bmatrix}  2.61667 \\  -2.79452 \\  7.00561 \end{bmatrix} }$%


$ \text{ -------------------------------------------------------------------------- } $%


\end{document}
```

Desde python lo escribe todo bastante bien, sin embargo no se como hacer para que este nuevo archivo.txt lo abra LaTeX y después lo ejecute para transformarlo en PDF.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda